# Having trouble with some homework

Tags: python, python-3.x

Question: *Write a python program using a "While" loop that will ask for the user to input exam scores. You should start by asking the user how many scores they would like to enter. Then use a loop to request each score and add it to a total. Finally, calculate and display the average for entered scores.*
The current code I have got is listed below though whenever I try to run it to see if it works, is comes up with Syntax Error: Invalid Syntax on the else.
I tried without else inside and outside the while loop and it came up with SyntaxErorr: Invalid Syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?

```
examNum = examCount
examCount = int(input("How many scores would you like to enter?"))

totalExam = (examCount + 1)
totalScore = sum(examScore)

while examNum  < examCount:
    examScore = int(input("Input your exam score."))
    else:
        print("Your average score is" totalScore)
```

Note: This is my first time doing Python in 5 - 10 years so I am back to square one with figuring everything else. I'm sure there is a obvious and easy work around but I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
examCount = int(input("How many scores would you like to enter?"))

exams = examCount
totalScore = 0

while examCount > 0:
    examScore = int(input("Input your exam score."))
    examCount -= 1
    totalScore += examScore

print(totalScore/exams)
```

Comment: Yeah this one worked best. Although the other ones were good, one did not use a while loop which didn't work for this part of the homework and the others were too complex for the level of python coding we are currently working with. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
# taking user input for total no of score of exam one want to count
socre_count = int(input("how many scores you would like to enter:" ))
# saving sum of scores in total_score
total_score = 0
# using index for making a loop
index = 0
# using while loop to iterate
while index < socre_count:
    # getting user input for each exam score
    exam_score = int(input("your exam score: "))
    total_score += exam_score # adding each score value to total
    index+=1 # increasing index
# calculating avg of total score
avg_score = total_score/socre_count
print(f"avg score is {avg_score}") # printing result
```

Answer (score 0):

First line says that:

```
examNum = examCount # NameError, we didn't declare examCount
```

Fifth line says:

```
totalScore = sum(examScore) # NameError, we didn't declare examScore
```

And the syntax Syntax mistakes at line 9-10:

The else keyword can be used only if there is keyword above on the same indentation level:

```
# Same level of indentation between while, and else:
....while True:
        pass
....else:
        pass

# Not same:
....while True:
        pass
........else:
            pass
```

And arguments must be passed into print statement via comas

```
print("Your average score is", totalScore)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
examCount = int(input("How many scores would you like to enter? "))
totalScore = 0
i = 0
while i < examCount:
    examScore = int(input("Input your exam score: "))
    totalScore += examScore
    i += 1
averageScore = totalScore / examCount
print("Your average score is ", averageScore)
```

I hope this will fix your issue!